# JFreeCharts Timeseries showing points

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have some code that will create a simple time series graph and save it as a JPEG. However, I cannot figure out how to have each data point with some sort of marker on it as well as XY information about in parenthesis (x,y) next to it. Could you guys point me in the right direction on how to approach this problem?

Comment: See also [`org.jfree.chart.annotations`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/package-frame.html).